# One mutex vs Multiple mutexes. Which one is better for the thread pool?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, locking, mutex

Example here, just want to protect the `iData` to ensure only one thread visit it at the same time.

```
struct myData;
myData iData;
```

Method 1, mutex inside the call function (multiple mutexes could be created):

```
    void _proceedTest(myData &data)
    {
       std::mutex mtx;
       std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(mtx);
       modifyData(data);
       lk.unlock;
    }

    int const nMaxThreads = std::thread::hardware_concurrency();
    vector<std::thread> threads;
    for (int iThread = 0; iThread < nMaxThreads; ++iThread)
    {
        threads.push_back(std::thread(_proceedTest, iData));
    }

    for (auto& th : threads) th.join();
```

Method2, use only one mutex:

```
    void _proceedTest(myData &data, std::mutex &mtx)
    {
       std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(mtx);
       modifyData(data);
       lk.unlock;
    }
    std::mutex mtx;
    int const nMaxThreads = std::thread::hardware_concurrency();
    vector<std::thread> threads;
    for (int iThread = 0; iThread < nMaxThreads; ++iThread)
    {
        threads.push_back(std::thread(_proceedTest, iData, mtx));
    }

    for (auto& th : threads) th.join();
```

1. I want to make sure that the Method 1 (multiple mutexes) ensures that only one thread can visit the iData at the same time.
2. If Method 1 is correct, not sure Method 1 is better of Method 2?
   Thanks!

Comment: You mean the Method 1 doens't guarantee that the iData is exclusively visited by only one thread?

Comment: How should it without the `std::mutex` shared between different threads?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1. I want to make sure that the Method 1 (multiple mutexes) ensures that only one thread can visit the iData at the same time.

Your 1st example creates a local mutex variable on the stack, it won't be shared with the other threads. Thus it's completely useless.
It won't guarantee exclusive access to `iData`.

> 2. If Method 1 is correct, not sure Method 1 is better of Method 2?

It isn't correct.

Comment: Just noticed the Method 2 is not correct neither. should use std::ref to wrap the iData and mtx

Comment: @lightrek You probably need [`std::ref()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/ref) to get it working correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Method 1 only works if you make the mutex variable `static`.

```
void _proceedTest(myData &data)
{
   static std::mutex mtx;
   std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(mtx);
   modifyData(data);
   lk.unlock;
}
```

This will make `mtx` be shared by all threads that enter `_proceedTest`.

Since a `static` function scope variable is only visible to users of the function, it is not really a sufficient lock for the passed in `data`. This is because it is conceivable that multiple threads could be calling different functions that each want to manipulate `data`.

Thus, even though Method 1 is salvageable, Method 2 is still better, even though the cohesion between the lock and the data is weak.

Answer (score 2):

The other answers are correct on the technical level, but there is an important language independent thing missing: you *always* prefer to minimize the number of different mutexes/locks/... !

Because: as soon as you have more than *one* thing that a thread needs to acquire in order to do something (to then release all acquired locks) **order** becomes crucial.

When you have **two** locks, and you have to different pieces of code, like:

```
getLockA() {
  getLockB() { 
   do something
  release B
release A
```

And

```
getLockB() {
  getLockA() {
```

you can quickly run into deadlocks - because two threads/processes can acquire one lock each - and then they are both stuck, waiting for the other one to release its lock. Of course - when looking at the above example "you would never make a mistake, and always go A first then B". But what if those locks exist in completely different parts of your application? And they aren't acquired in the same method or class, but over the course of say 3, 5 nested method invocations?

Thus: when you can solve your problem with one lock - use **one** lock only! The more locks you need to get something done, the higher the risk to end up in dead locks.

Answer (score 0):

The mutex in version 1 will go out of scope once you leave the _proceedTest scope, locking a mutex like that makes no sense because it will never be accessible to the other thread.

In the second version multiple threads can share the mutex (as long as it doesn't go out of scope, for example as a class member), this way one thread can lock it and the other thread can see that it is locked (and won't be able to lock it aswell, hence the term mutual exclusion).